# Reversing a string - Loop doesn't execute

Tags: c, for-loop, reverse

I wrote a program that reverses the chars in the words of a sentence (without using string functions such as `strrev`,etc). Here is an example of what it should do

input - `hi john`
output - `ih nhoj`

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int i,j,k=0,count=0;
char a[100],temp;
printf("enter name\n");
gets(a);
while(a[k]!=0)
{
    count++;
    k++;
}
printf("%d\n",count);
for(i=0,j=count;i<j;i++,j--)
{
    temp=a[i];
    a[i]=a[j];
    a[j]=temp;
}
printf("%s\n",a);
}
```

The problem is that the `fo`r loop isn't executing, only `while` loop executes.

Please help.

Comment: Even after fixing the problem, your program won't output `ih nhoj` for input `hi john`. It will output `nhoj ih` instead.

Comment: u r right..i am working on it..confident of getting it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should realize that at the end of the while loop `count` stores the length of the string entered.For example if you input `hello` `count` holds `5`.But the last element of the string will be at `count-1` index and not at `count` index as indexing starts from `0`.

So you should set `j` to `count-1`.Also having main return `int` is a good practice.

Answer (score 3):

The starting value of `j` should be `count-1`, not `count`. The element at the `count`th location is the zero terminator which don't want to swap!

```
for(i=0,j=count-1;i<j;i++,j--)
               ^^
```

Don't use `gets()` as it can't prevent against buffer overflow and use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html). `gets()` has been removed from C11 (latest C standard). The one thing you need to take when using `fgets()` is that it will also read in the newline character if there's sufficient space in the buffer which you need to remove.

Answer (score -1):

> replace

```
for(i=0,j=count;i<j;i++,j--)
```

> with

```
for(i=0,j=count-1;i<j;i++,j--)
```